# VBA coding to timestamp an adjacent cell when it’s value changes via vLookup

Tags: vba, timestamp, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet I am working on that has some coding done to it in VBA. I have a column labeled quantity and a column 2 columns to the right called "out date" that I want it to timestamp when "quantity" is populated

The values in column "quantity" are filled in via vlookup from another sheet in the workbook.

I noticed that if I manually enter a value in the “quantity column the timestamp works perfectly, yet once I set it up via vlookup it no longer enters the timestamp in column "out date".

My code for this process currently is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCellColumn As Integer
    Dim xTimecolumn As Integer
    Dim xRow, xCol As Integer

    xCellColumn = 11
    xTimecolumn = 13
    xRow = Target.Row
    xCol = Target.Column

    If Target.Text <> "" Then
        If xCol = xColumn Then
            Cells(xRow, xTimecolumn) = Now()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Is it possible to still have a timestamp automatically entered when the value is entered via vlookup?

I've done some extensive searching and all I can find is how to timestamp when a cell value changes by entering it

Comment: Unfortunately, You will need to write a macro that will check the cells value on a consistent time interval (every 10 seconds? Minute? Half hour?) depends on how accurate you want your time stamp.

Comment: Edit your question, add 4 leading spaces to each line that should appear in code. Or highlight all of your code and hit CTRL+K

Comment: Thanks for the tip!, and I would say maybe to have it look every 1 minute would be an ideal rate for it to check. Would the code for this be very extensive?

Comment: Are you entering the values in column "quantity" as part of another macro? I think so, but not sure. If so, couldn't you add the timestamp step to that macro? Otherwise disregard the suggestion.

Comment: I did end up adding in the timestamp to my existing macro, i just didn’t know how to write the code to make it timestamp but I have figured it out now. Thanks!